# Connecting to AWS with PuTTY always times out. Any reason why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, putty

I'm new to working with AWS and want to connect to an existing Linux EC2 instance (I'm on Windows 10).

Here's what I've done:

1. I've logged into AWS and have opened my instance.
2. I've created a new Key Pair and downloaded it as a `.ppk` file
3. I started PuTTY, and selected 'Connect' on my intance. I copied the Public DNS into the PuTTY Host Name field (`root@ec2-1-23-456.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com`).
4. Then in Connection>SSH>Auth I upload the saved `.ppk` file.
5. I then hit open.

PuTTY opens a blank terminal window with nothing on it then after about 5 secs an alert box appears saying "Network Error: Connection timed out".

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what to do next. Would anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like your security group is not setup to accept SSH connections from your IP.

Answer (score 0):

When an SSH connection times-out, it is normally an indication that network traffic is not getting to the Amazon EC2 instance.

Things to check:

- The instance is running **Linux**
- The instance is launched in a **public subnet**, which is defined as having a Route Table entry to points to an Internet Gateway
- The instance has a **public IP address**, which you are using for the connection
- The **Network Access Control Lists** (NACLs) are set to their default "Allow All" values
- A **Security Group** associated with the instance that permits inbound access on port 22 (SSH) either from your IP address, or from the Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`)
- Your **corporate network** permits an outbound SSH connection (try alternate networks, eg home vs work vs tethered to your phone)

See also: [Troubleshooting connecting to your instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html)

You did not mention Security Groups in your Question, so that would be the first thing to check.